# intended c++ virtual function not getting called

Tags: c++

this my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"**

class IPlayback
{
      public:
           virtual void createRenderStream() = 0; 
};

class ICapture 
{
      public:
          virtual void createCaptureStream() = 0; 

};

class IAudioStackInterface
{
   public:
      virtual void createStream() = 0; 
};

class CAudioClientInterface : public IAudioStackInterface,
                              public ICapture,
                              public IPlayback

{
        void createCaptureStream()
        { 
            printf("\n i am in createCaptureStream");
        }

        void createRenderStream()
        {
            printf("\n i am in createRenderStream");
        }

        void createStream()
        {
            printf("\n i am in createStream");
        }
};


typedef IAudioStackInterface* PIAudioStackInterface;
typedef ICapture* PCapture;
typedef IPlayback* PIPlayback;
typedef void* PVOID;

int main()
{
    PVOID pObj = new CAudioClientInterface();
    PIPlayback pPlayBackInterfcace = (PIPlayback) pObj;
    pPlayBackInterfcace->createRenderStream();
    return 0;
}
```

I should get createRenderstream printed whereas i am getting createStream printed?

Comment: Member for 2 years, 17 questions asked, and you still can't format your code when you post a question ???

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
PIPlayback pPlayBackInterfcace = (PIPlayback)(CAudioClientInterface*) pObj;
```

You are only allowed to cast to `void*` and back to the original type `CAudioClientInterface*`. Casting to another type is undefined behavior.

Comment: Or better still, don't convert to `void*` in the first place. Why would you want to throw away type checking?

Comment: @MikeSeymour sometimes you are forced to convert to `void*`, e.g. when using an API that uses `void*` to pass data to a callback function.